# Jasper Reports - Criar linha vertical no Detail

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estou com um problema meio complicado, uso o xpath para gerar dados de um xml para o relatório e quando coloco as informações no detail, eles aparecem normalmente, mas a linha vertical não fica até o final. Um exemplo do problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa linha vertical é a borda do próprio field

Answer (score -1):

Tente utilizar a banda "Background", criando a estrutura das linhas da "Detail" em seu tamanho total. Desta forma não será mais necessário utilizar a borda dos fields.